# How to find initial object of the category of pointed rings?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, ring-homomorphism, slice-category

I have the category of pointed rings. Objects are all pairs $(R, r)$ where $R$ - ring (with 1) and r is the element of R. Morphisms are homomorphism of rings. Morphism $(R, r) \longrightarrow (R', r')$ exist if exist homomorphism p: $R \longrightarrow
 R'$ and $p(r)=r'$.

Can somebody help to find initial object or proof that it doesn't exist? I think that it doesn't exist but can't find a way to proof.

Thanks.

Comment: So what are the morphisms here? What is a morphism from $(R, r)$ to $(S, s)$ in this category? Is it merely a ring homomorphism from $R$ to $S$? (No; why?)

Comment: Okay, you answered that part in your updated question. That leads to the answer.

Comment: At least intuitively, it seems to make more sense that it would be the ring formed by the integers with the usual multiplication/etc., with any integer as the fixed point. After all, we can't have a ring with no elements, and the initial object in the category of rings is the usual ring of the integers, so I'm not exactly sure how there would be a difference if you fix a particular point. (This as opposed to the category of sets - with initial object the empty set - and the category of pointed sets - with initial object a singleton set.) Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious though.

Comment: Homomorphism can't just change one element to another. It must save structure unlike pointed sets

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You can't take *any* integer as the fixed point; morphisms of rings preserve $0$ (and $1$), so you can't have a morphism $(\mathbb{Z},0)\to (R,r)$ in the cases where $r\neq 0$. You will have the same problem with $1$ instead of $0$, and also with any multiple of $1$. So in fact no integer can work.

Comment: I would presume it is $(\mathbb{Z}\langle x \rangle , x)$ given that the property he wants is more or less the universal property of the free algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$. (every ring with $1$ has a canonical map from $\mathbb{Z}$ into it and the marked point gives the evaluation of $x$, so the univ property of the free algebra gives us a unique morhism from  $\mathbb{Z}\langle x \rangle$ into any pointed ring sending $x$ to $r$)

Comment: @M. Vinay, yes, it's a definition of initial object.

Comment: @Enkidu What is morphism from (Z(x), x) to (Z(x), 0) for example?

Comment: the morphism setting $x$ to $0$, i.e. just remembering the constant coefficient and then injecting it back in. you know about the univ property of the free algebra of a set over $\mathbb{Z}$, don't you? Also, your notation is off, those $Z$ need to be $\mathbb{Z}$ and the round brackets need to be either $\langle \rangle$ or $[]$ as we are talking about the free algebra or polynomial algebra (which coincide here since $x$ is only a singleton set) and not about also adjoining inverses of $x$.

Comment: @Ivan Shatspenkov I am also now sure it is an initial object, as I said, the two universal properties just literally translate into each other!

Comment: @Enkidu I read some articles about free algebra, but I'm newby in this. I'll figure it out.

Comment: well, they are on one generator $x$ just defined by the universal property that any choice $r$ of element in another algebra over that ring gives a unique morphism such that $x\mapsto r$, now every ring with one is a $mathbb{Z}$-algebra

Comment: @Enkidu Can you please give me some links to info about the universal property of free algebra or polynomial ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to unique isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}[x],x)$ as this has the universal property that any assignement $x \mapsto r\in R$ gives a unique morphism $$\mathbb{Z}[x] \to R$$
hence any choice of $(r,R)$ gives you such a unique map and hence it is the initial object.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome, sorry that i did not post it as answer immediately but as comment, those homological algebra arguments usually blow up quite fast, so I just like to give pointers, but turned out here it was actually a 3 liner. Also I was confuesd as being the first one to see this.